# Set PDF to be printed instead of webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

Currently I am a junior developer who is trying to create github.io resume that is friendly for employers. I worked in chrome and managed to set up correct print settings that work correctly in chrome and firefox but not safari or edge.

In chrome and firefox my print formats to 2 pages, where as in safari and edge it formats to 4 pages.

One of the first things I set up was a "download pdf" button that downloads a nicely formatted pdf which is the exact same format as my working print settings. I also want the general print button to work and send out the same format so if my download pdf button isn't used the employer can still have a friendly print format.

If there anyway I can set it up so when print is selected from the menu it uses my pdf instead printing out the webpage? This would save me a lot of time setting up print settings for each browser and the print can be reliable across browsers.

I am open to using scripts to make this work.

Comment: In JS you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeprint with decent browser support. But AFAIK you cannot prevent the real print dialog, your JS just runs before/after it

Answer (score 0):

You can consider [jspdf](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF), or you can write `@media print` and identify styles you want printed and how it should appear.

Regarding your latest comment - since your page is only static elements, why don't you simply create a PDF, upload it to your server, and provide a linked button to the PDF. Simplest way is to create something in Photoshop (or even simpler - in MS Word), save it as a PDF and go that route.

Comment: Yeah I have an @media print, but its not cross browser compatible. Sorry, I should have specified that, it is what i intent to mean when I stated print settings.

I can set up settings for each browser but would prefer to take the easiest route available. 

I already have a pdf and would prefer when print is selected from the browser menu it prints the pdf instead of the webpage. Currently there is a button to download the pdf, to not rely on the user clicking that button I want to print settings to function correctly to.

Comment: Before the page is printed, is it loaded with dynamic information, or is the information always the same? For example, is what's being printed the contents of a shopping cart (dynamic)? Or is it the content of your "about us" page (static)?

Comment: Its static, there are no dynamic elements. Its just single page made with html css.

Comment: yeah I have that already, stated in my original description. 

From what I have found out on my own it seems what I want isn't an option. I used normalize to help some of the cross browser issues but its still not 100%. I am working on setting up print settings for safari and edge and just hope in the meantime that just my pdf button is used.

I was just hoping there was a way to link that pdf to my print instead of having to set up different media queries for each browser.

Comment: I re-read your initial question. If I'm understanding correctly, you want to send specific information to the printer, but through the browser's print button? Your logic doesn't make sense. Why wouldn't an employer use a print button that's right in front of them? Why would anyone go through the extra steps to File > Print?

Comment: Here's something you can check out. It works for me in multiple browsers. Maybe there something in my stylesheet that will help you. See this [codepen](https://codepen.io/newnam/pen/MQaBXB).

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer my question. I understand that it may not be the most direct question and think you may be misunderstanding my intentions. If its someones habit to right click and print, that is what they are going to do. Why or why not isn't really something I'm trying to answer, I'm trying to cover ground so all methods work as expected. If a potential employer asks why I formatted my resume to print out terribly I'm not going ask them why they didn't use the pdf button both methods should work.